# How to allocate memory from specific region

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Normally, one can use the `malloc` and `free` functions to allocate memory in an implementation-defined manner. However, often times one needs to manage the allocation of memory from a specific region. Examples include:

- Inter-process shared memory
- Memory-mapped files
- Non-volatile memory

Instead of writing a one-off heap implementation each time this requirement occurs, is there a way to re-use `malloc` to manage these regions (Linux)? Otherwise, can any of the "well-known" memory allocators (e.g. dmalloc, ptmalloc, etc.) support allocating from a specific region?

Example:

```
void *pool = mmap(/* my file */);
void *pool_manager = mallloc_init(pool, /* size */);
void *p = malloc_ex(pool, 1024);
free_ex(pool, p);
```

Comment: I don't think you can reuse `malloc`. I might be wrong, but I believe you'll need implement your own function for that.

Comment: some memory regions are writable without the need of malloc. On some platforms there's an "absolute allocate" call, and on some others, the shared memory is writable, period, but you need a convention (semaphore) to be sure that you're not writing concurrently

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Obviously all these types of memory can be directly read/written. The question is if one can re-use well-known allocators to keep track of it. I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: To the extent that the question goes beyond "can `malloc()` do this?" (which it can't), this seems come down to a request for a recommendation of a third-party library.  I'm afraid such requests are off-topic here.

Comment: Search for Linux shared memory: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=AuiBWsOyO8PcjwOH_KyYDQ&q=linux+shared+memory&oq=linux+shared+memory&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.3363.8904.0.9683.27.23.4.0.0.0.142.1947.15j8.23.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.27.1964...46j0i131k1j0i46k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1j0i10k1.0.78z0pwXpIQQ

Comment: Are you looking for a memory pool implementation? If not, it might be better to clarify.

Comment: @68ejxfcj5669: You might be looking for the `mmap()` function.

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not exist. Neither `malloc` nor any of its drop-in replacements can do that.

So, let us now get into why this stuff does not exist.

Inter-process shared memory is indeed shared between processes, but at different addresses in different processes, so a traditional heap manager does not work at all and specialized protocols are used to communicate between the processes that use things other than pointers (because pointers don't work cross-process because the addresses are different).

The same is true of memory mapped files. For memory-mapped files, typically the file format is still very-well-defined and nothing like a heap manager would be in it, and if there were it would be fully specified by the file format and you might find the thing in libraries for that file format, but a drop-in heap manager would never work. If you start talking about a heap manager in a memory-mapped file I think you're developing a database engine, and you're about to find out that heap management needs to be very different from in-RAM heap management because disk seek times are horrible.

I suppose you could use a heap manager for non-volatile memory for deeply embedded systems, but most of those use the far simpler technique of NVRAM is always statically allocated. My gut feeling is a general heap manager is a poor choice and a specialized manager attuned to the problem is so much better that nobody really considers a generic heap manager.

If you did find a general purpose heap library that took a memory region to use as a heap it would still work badly for you. Shared memory and memory-mapped files have to deal with the process crashing between any two instructions; thus can't use normal locking at all. There are specialized locks that are used for shared memory. The problem for memory-mapped IO is even worse and I can prove the locks cannot exist because the concurrency model is too bad.